# explode function doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a String `7*10*6*` I will separate the numbers, when I use explode function the out is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => *
)
```

here is my code:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(explode('7*10*6','*'));
echo '</pre>';
```

what's the problem?

Comment: This question is off-topic because we _at least_ expect you to consult the manual before asking …

Comment: The problem is simply that the parameters are the wrong way round. The delimiter (in your case `*`) is the **first** argument, and the string you wish to "explode" as the **second**. This however is backwards in the code snippet you provided :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oh boy, have you read the manual of explode?
the manual says:
`explode(string $delimiter,string $string)`. You have done wrong. change your code to this:

```
print_r(explode('*','7*10*6'));
```

Comment: I upvoted just for the 'Oh boy'.

Comment: thank you behzad, it had stopped me from working two hours.

Answer (score 5):

**Try**

```
print_r(explode('*','7*10*6'));
```

In explode function first argument is separator and second is string.